# Android NullPointerException while copying exif tags

Tags: android, image, bitmap, nullpointerexception, exif

I am trying to re-size an image, that part completed.
Then I'm trying to copy exif tags to new file.
I use ExifInterface to read tags.
I know it's an interface not an object.
But When I try to use it for really big sized image, I get `NullPointerException`.
I get this error not for all the images.

```
07-25 11:59:23.870: WARN/System.err(1362): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 11:59:23.870: WARN/System.err(1362):     at android.media.ExifInterface.saveAttributes(ExifInterface.java:202)
```

How do I solve it?

Code to copy exif information

```
try {
    // copy paste exif information from original file to new
    // file
    ExifInterface oldexif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
    ExifInterface newexif = new ExifInterface(file.getPath());

    int build = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    // From API 11
    if (build >= 11) {
        newexif.setAttribute("FNumber",
                oldexif.getAttribute("FNumber"));
        newexif.setAttribute("ExposureTime",
                oldexif.getAttribute("ExposureTime"));
        newexif.setAttribute("ISOSpeedRatings",
                oldexif.getAttribute("ISOSpeedRatings"));
    }
    // From API 9
    if (build >= 9) {
        newexif.setAttribute("GPSAltitude",
                oldexif.getAttribute("GPSAltitude"));
        newexif.setAttribute("GPSAltitudeRef",
                oldexif.getAttribute("GPSAltitudeRef"));
    }
    // From API 8
    if (build >= 8) {
        newexif.setAttribute("FocalLength",
                oldexif.getAttribute("FocalLength"));
        newexif.setAttribute("GPSDateStamp",
                oldexif.getAttribute("GPSDateStamp"));
        newexif.setAttribute("GPSProcessingMethod",
                oldexif.getAttribute("GPSProcessingMethod"));
        newexif.setAttribute("GPSTimeStamp",
                oldexif.getAttribute("GPSTimeStamp"));
    }
    newexif.setAttribute("DateTime",
            oldexif.getAttribute("DateTime"));
    newexif.setAttribute("Flash", oldexif.getAttribute("Flash"));
    newexif.setAttribute("GPSLatitude",
            oldexif.getAttribute("GPSLatitude"));
    newexif.setAttribute("GPSLatitudeRef",
            oldexif.getAttribute("GPSLatitudeRef"));
    newexif.setAttribute("GPSLongitude",
            oldexif.getAttribute("GPSLongitude"));
    newexif.setAttribute("GPSLongitudeRef",
            oldexif.getAttribute("GPSLongitudeRef"));

    // You need to update this with your new height width
    newexif.setAttribute("ImageLength",
            oldexif.getAttribute("ImageLength"));
    newexif.setAttribute("ImageWidth",
            oldexif.getAttribute("ImageWidth"));

    newexif.setAttribute("Make", oldexif.getAttribute("Make"));
    newexif.setAttribute("Model", oldexif.getAttribute("Model"));
    newexif.setAttribute("Orientation",
            oldexif.getAttribute("Orientation"));
    newexif.setAttribute("WhiteBalance",
            oldexif.getAttribute("WhiteBalance"));

    newexif.saveAttributes();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Image resized & saved successfully",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Additional onFly information:

New file is created when I'm trying to read both the file:
[image]

---

Debug watch on oldexif
[image]

---

Debug watch on newexif
[image]

---

Testing image

http://vikaskanani.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/test.jpg

---

Using Android emulator for sdk 2.1

Comment: Are you shore that all image are taged ? because what it seems to be is that some are not tagged. On the catch try to print the files the names of that files and see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a null value somewhere in the saveAttributes.

Debugging NullPointerExceptions is very easy, providing you have the sourcecode.

Below you can find the sourcecode for the ExifInterface for Android 2.1

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/media/ExifInterface.java#ExifInterface

line 202 contains this :

```
sb.append(val.length() + " ");
```

Only thing that can be null here is val. (one of the values you're passing in the saveAttributes method).

I would suggest double checking the values you're passing onto that value, and watch out for null values.

Comment: Yes, Till today I was also thinking that this error is very easy to solve. But today, I was confused with interface. While setting attributes, String parameter cannot be null, so just adding "" is enough!

Comment: Google code ideally should have thrown an IllegalArgumentException or something, indicating what attribute was null. Would have been easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach to copying EXIF data is to use the Sanselan Android library. The ExifInterface has data corruption bugs on some versions, and also handles a limited number number of EXIF tags.

Here is blog post that talks about copying EXIF data using Sanselan and provides sample code:
http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/copying-exif-metadata-using-sanselan/

Comment: Great! In my case I only deal with longitude and latitude!