# Writing EXIF metadata onto images from Android Apps into Windows

Tags: android, windows, sqlite, exif

I would like to write the EXIF images from the Android Apps.The EXIF information can be displayed in Windows by right-clicking the properties of the images. Camera methods in my application can provide me a bitmap, which I store in the storage (MediaStore) device , the location of the photo where the user captures , and the properties of the picture strings.
The above information are stored in SQLite database

In addition to this, I want to add a few tags to the picture in its metadata by writing the data from the database or hard-coding the Text.setText().

EXIF is a popolar way to do so but I couldn't find good references on how to do this.

If there are some tools to achieve this task in Android programming, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812711/android-nullpointerexception-while-copying-exif-tags

Comment: Do you mean finding the string variable  to store the information from database and write into EXIF metadata, from the website below : 

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/media/ExifInterface.java#ExifInterface